# Get-HotFix not returning all installed KBs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, windows-update

I'm having trouble with the `Get-HotFix` command on a Windows Server 2012 not returning all installed KBs, compared to what Windows Update says is actually installed on the server when querying it.

**Get-HotFix Script:**

```
Get-HotFix | Select-Object HotFixID | Where-Object { $_.HotFixId.ToUpper().StartsWith("KB") } | ForEach-Object { Write-Output "PACKAGE:$($_.HotFixId)" }
```

**Windows Update Script**

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Searcher.ServerSelection = 2
$InstalledUpdates = $Searcher.Search("IsInstalled=1")
ForEach ($Update in $InstalledUpdates.Updates) {
    Foreach ($KB_ID in $Update.KBArticleIDs) {
        Write-Output "PACKAGE_WUA:KB$($KB_ID)|$($Update.Identity.UpdateID)"
    }
}
```

**Output of the Get-HotFix Script:**

```
PACKAGE:KB3191564
PACKAGE:KB2868626
PACKAGE:KB2883200
PACKAGE:KB2887595
PACKAGE:KB2903939
PACKAGE:KB2911106
PACKAGE:KB2919355
PACKAGE:KB2919394
PACKAGE:KB2920189
PACKAGE:KB2928680
PACKAGE:KB2934520
PACKAGE:KB2938066
PACKAGE:KB2954879
PACKAGE:KB2955164
PACKAGE:KB2961908
PACKAGE:KB2967917
PACKAGE:KB2975061
PACKAGE:KB2977765
PACKAGE:KB2978041
PACKAGE:KB2978126
PACKAGE:KB2989930
PACKAGE:KB2999226
PACKAGE:KB3000483
PACKAGE:KB3000850
PACKAGE:KB3003057
PACKAGE:KB3004365
PACKAGE:KB3004545
PACKAGE:KB3012702
PACKAGE:KB3013172
PACKAGE:KB3013769
PACKAGE:KB3013791
PACKAGE:KB3013816
PACKAGE:KB3014442
PACKAGE:KB3019978
PACKAGE:KB3021910
PACKAGE:KB3023222
PACKAGE:KB3023266
PACKAGE:KB3024751
PACKAGE:KB3024755
PACKAGE:KB3030947
PACKAGE:KB3033446
PACKAGE:KB3035126
PACKAGE:KB3036612
PACKAGE:KB3037579
PACKAGE:KB3038002
PACKAGE:KB3042085
PACKAGE:KB3044374
PACKAGE:KB3044673
PACKAGE:KB3045634
PACKAGE:KB3045685
PACKAGE:KB3045717
PACKAGE:KB3045719
PACKAGE:KB3045755
PACKAGE:KB3045999
PACKAGE:KB3046017
PACKAGE:KB3046737
PACKAGE:KB3054169
PACKAGE:KB3054203
PACKAGE:KB3054256
PACKAGE:KB3054464
PACKAGE:KB3055323
PACKAGE:KB3055343
PACKAGE:KB3055642
PACKAGE:KB3059317
PACKAGE:KB3060793
PACKAGE:KB3061512
PACKAGE:KB3063843
PACKAGE:KB3064209
PACKAGE:KB3065822
PACKAGE:KB3065988
PACKAGE:KB3068708
PACKAGE:KB3071756
PACKAGE:KB3074228
PACKAGE:KB3074548
PACKAGE:KB3075853
PACKAGE:KB3077715
PACKAGE:KB3078071
PACKAGE:KB3078405
PACKAGE:KB3078676
PACKAGE:KB3080149
PACKAGE:KB3082089
PACKAGE:KB3084135
PACKAGE:KB3084905
PACKAGE:KB3086255
PACKAGE:KB3087137
PACKAGE:KB3091297
PACKAGE:KB3094486
PACKAGE:KB3095701
PACKAGE:KB3097997
PACKAGE:KB3098779
PACKAGE:KB3099834
PACKAGE:KB3100473
PACKAGE:KB3102429
PACKAGE:KB3102467
PACKAGE:KB3103616
PACKAGE:KB3103696
PACKAGE:KB3103709
PACKAGE:KB3109103
PACKAGE:KB3109976
PACKAGE:KB3110329
PACKAGE:KB3112148
PACKAGE:KB3112336
PACKAGE:KB3115224
PACKAGE:KB3118401
PACKAGE:KB3121261
PACKAGE:KB3122654
PACKAGE:KB3123245
PACKAGE:KB3124275
```

**Output of the Windows Update script :**

```
PACKAGE_WUA:KB925673|07609d43-d518-4e77-856e-d1b316d1b8a8
PACKAGE_WUA:KB2538243|729a0dcb-df9e-4d02-b603-ed1aee074428
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3023266|8ffb7a9e-cafe-456f-a219-13b3e7a56ed2
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3019978|2628719c-4abd-46e2-93e8-fe53c19c3117
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3000483|4361108d-d09b-4c4d-8b2f-f1167f7b8c57
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3035126|3fea2186-fb39-41f1-9214-55a5bb5552e6
PACKAGE_WUA:KB2919355|8452bac0-bf53-4fbd-915d-499de08c338b
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3045755|36696f1a-eb7a-48db-a69b-fae68b1fbf58
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3045999|4678f8b9-0b81-4f8b-853f-4adfed9262a6
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3045685|5d50743b-e648-4acc-8986-a7bc5aa53f71
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3055642|02ee413c-7bbb-4fe0-bd97-9e931a2208e1
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3059317|8bb29af2-47b2-439e-b999-3176c23a8e8b
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3061512|54110383-c46c-4424-a8ef-9cd6b7a20025
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3004365|fb95c1c8-de23-4089-ae29-fd3351d55421
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3046017|4b7876f0-b962-4c4c-9e45-fe35b0c801ce
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3071756|f7c02df0-0cb8-4a56-b367-7efd5c9bc9ac
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3082089|7c5f1dad-2f35-4120-b4ad-c5947edf0567
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3084135|04f04253-f803-43b8-8b37-6841c614dd9f
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3086255|c848ed4a-5e2e-43dc-bd1b-cb2f717e90cd
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3109103|d928f50f-191e-4858-b546-acda983da182
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3110329|27ae312b-1b1a-4f18-a574-3dfe46244d3a
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3126593|3ce61d87-7153-4540-a74b-fd0065edfdde
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3133043|1bc49ccc-409b-4d07-93b7-cea850ea0d78
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3126041|aa793ff1-f4b7-42b1-9f24-6f11b50f952c
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3126434|6b6a5779-3fe5-4789-aba6-0c3e9b802b37
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3126587|214b1f40-24ed-4dae-9e76-237763c5c8ca
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3135998|8069b13a-3bf0-4e14-a80b-d5cd3acc42ed
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3139398|dd382658-effd-4e24-abca-877e1915bf6d
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3139914|06eae584-188d-4a35-805a-ef98beddcd3d
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3146723|209e2d1e-330f-4dcc-b705-5999c2f38385
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3156059|05ba4c3c-81c2-4c19-9899-a4a18716cddb
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3155784|20d1a457-eca7-488d-a870-96d7374cb436
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3159398|d9f4e1b5-4477-4d83-8c27-111ce0e88dd8
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3161949|67a00639-09a1-4c5f-83ff-394e7601fc03
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3162343|ba0f75ff-19c3-4cbd-a3f3-ef5b5c0f88bf
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3172729|cdde339c-ebdb-4a16-add4-fb196a5053a8
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3175024|77798aee-dc0e-409a-875c-7134c8a93766
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3178539|e90f9283-7304-4a98-a5ec-98bd2a3163e7
PACKAGE_WUA:KB3205400|ff4c348a-c6c2-4bbc-af33-01ef3ae1cc6e
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4012213|80bc2b42-a953-4096-8595-130e9a9c9fb9
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4015547|79629e4e-67eb-438d-9420-17c673012731
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4019213|2913676b-33a1-4557-9160-f36bfed5f294
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4019111|2e2dc8c8-c324-4968-9461-1c5c6f1190c1
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4022717|7b6c010d-36ea-4bb4-9d06-9e44c1235690
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4025333|a8091733-a526-4480-afe7-72a1b3385439
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4034672|1d84c38c-d2dd-4ad8-acd7-19d9391de17f
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4038793|9516efa8-6493-43de-979c-ebf2aa89aa69
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4041687|e36e24fc-789e-483f-bb72-01a3ec3eea74
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4048961|896142dc-9329-403d-98e0-229567e995d9
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4054522|89bb3c1a-4825-4ae3-a42f-ad0ae8c86c1a
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4056898|29159163-0da5-456d-92a5-9bd853a401ae
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4055271|0f6efea5-e7fe-4bab-80fa-4033e4a017ab
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4074597|f5df629a-edb7-49f1-946d-18e4f0a860f0
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4088879|913c1d08-eb63-4b74-aeff-a476d1fbaa2c
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4093115|33be9fcf-aef5-44fd-8164-e6b8baa88549
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4103715|196f3a64-83fb-4123-a71b-3e7aa0534b4a
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4099639|041c9d83-7a16-4e5d-8f2b-35d5cca0fc62
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4284878|45636cfd-ab6b-4db5-a310-712f3663eae6
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4338824|007ce1f3-3a12-40ef-8389-322068b780a7
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4340006|1d638098-af3d-4ca5-84e1-db9cb0e82ae4
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4339284|d91c89a6-0ef2-4b57-961d-f3f657de9d66
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4343888|ed4981c9-7aa7-4e1f-bdd5-b43d2afae17a
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4345681|c601cf7a-ba23-4d6d-bcdc-c61c258e7f1f
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4457143|b4e784a4-9907-4d25-90ef-858bcafcf450
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4462941|07cf0ca5-397c-46ee-9093-b1e5dbce59bb
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4462901|cecc9666-c679-4104-9ba0-bfe206d181a5
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4468323|03a8098b-7740-40da-9082-00ea285035be
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4471322|39654137-cb30-429e-b09a-2c39055716c1
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4471983|0fcc811c-48de-4c15-8240-5ccdb8171d8b
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4480964|45e80aae-4277-4c87-bd05-5cc8c6dd672e
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4487123|aa180d6a-6b08-4f8b-8e93-682de0657164
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4487080|e69d46be-4fe0-4d50-baf6-6091109d90ab
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4487028|0b256bc7-170d-4ee7-a993-8e9fac37a589
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4486459|adbc9c77-f9ba-4224-8b5c-4ae453898c2b
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4489883|dded804a-129f-4644-899c-e49ccd2bad2c
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4490128|c49cf4bb-325d-4752-ae32-33e053fabaf2
PACKAGE_WUA:KB890830|c991073f-ca3e-467d-b5a0-c8574b289b96
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4493435|94debd3d-b7b7-42e0-9645-11a4e8c83772
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4493467|8693f170-0aea-4539-bc72-feffa6e947ba
PACKAGE_WUA:KB4493446|a946a42f-5514-49bd-8a5c-42bf6354d8e4
```

As you can see, the following KBs (61) are missing from the `Get-HotFix` command output:

```
KB925673, KB2538243, KB3126593, KB3133043, KB3126041, KB3126434, KB3126587, KB3135998, KB3139398, KB3139914, KB3146723, KB3156059, KB3155784, KB3159398, KB3161949, KB3162343, KB3172729, KB3175024, KB3178539, KB3205400, KB4012213, KB4015547, KB4019213, KB4019111, KB4022717, KB4025333, KB4034672, KB4038793, KB4041687, KB4048961, KB4054522, KB4056898, KB4055271, KB4074597, KB4088879, KB4093115, KB4103715, KB4099639, KB4284878, KB4338824, KB4340006, KB4339284, KB4343888, KB4345681, KB4457143, KB4462941, KB4462901, KB4468323, KB4471322, KB4471983, KB4480964, KB4487123, KB4487080, KB4487028, KB4486459, KB4489883, KB4490128, KB890830, KB4493435, KB4493467, KB4493446
```

The last one (KB4493446) for instance is the cumulative for April 2019.

My questions are :

- What makes it so that `Get-HotFix` returns less KBs than when querying Windows Update?
- What would be a good workaround to retrieve all installed KBs **without having to be connected to the internet**?

Comment: Did you see the note from the MS Docs page? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-hotfix?view=powershell-5.1 `This class returns only the updates supplied by Component Based Servicing (CBS). These updates are not listed in the registry. Updates supplied by Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) or the Windows Update site are not returned by Win32_QuickFixEngineering. For more information, see Win32_QuickFixEngineering class.`

Comment: Thanks! What could be an alternative to Get-HotFix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to use Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) ?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism

You can use dism directly :

```perl
dism /online /get-packages
```

`/online` don't means that you need internet but only that the target the current system.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-global-options-for-command-line-syntax

If you prefer powershell, you can also use the Powershell DISM wrapper :

```
Get-WindowsPackage -Online
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/previous-versions/windows/powershell-scripting/dn376488(v=wps.620)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working well!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the WMI method?

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_QuickFixEngineering -namespace "root\cimv2" | Select-Object -Property HotFixID | Out-String
```

EDIT

Ignore that answer. I believe Get-HotFix uses WMI anyway. I found [this solution](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1384555) and it yields different results for me:

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()

$UpdateHistory = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount)
$KBs = @()

foreach ($Update in $UpdateHistory) { 
                [regex]::match($Update.Title,'(KB[0-9]{6,7})').value | Where-Object {$_ -ne ""} | foreach { 
                    $KB = New-Object -TypeName PSObject 
                    $KB | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name KB -Value $_ 
                    $KB | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Title -Value $Update.Title  
                    $KB | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $Update.Description
                    $KB | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $Update.Date    
                    $KBs += $KB
                } 
            } 

$KBs | Select KB,Title,Description,Date
```

Comment: I've tried that approach, but sometimes if some KBs were uninstalled, they are still listed without their associated uninstall events

Comment: Ah, that's annoying. I guess the only sure fire way to know what's definitely installed would be to query the registry @ Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Answer (score 0):

Answers based on `New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"` will not show any updates installed prior to a reset of Windows Update (done by deleting SoftwareDistribution folder), `"Microsoft.Update.Session"` will only show updates which were installed since the WU reset (WU reset described e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934703/reset-windows-updates)

`Get-WindowsPackage -Online` works regardless, so it is more reliable, however, it does not show updates for other MS products (e.g. for SQL server):
[comparison of installed software vs Get-WindowsPackage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRsTp.png)

Updates for other MS products are shown in registry `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`, however regular Windows updates are not listed there, so the only reliable method I found so far is to combine the results from registry and from `Get-WindowsPackage -Online`

EDIT
`Get-WindowsPackage` is also missing some  Windows Updates packages, comparison of `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering`   (on the right side) vs on the left side: `Get-WindowsPackage`
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUIKp.png) so seems like the only reliable solution is to combine multiple sources of data.